# Intent for facebook signup/register page in android

Tags: android, facebook

I have a link in my application that needs to display the sign up page of Facebook. Is there and intent that i can start that will open a browser or android application to display it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can signup/register facebook page from your application. Refer the link [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) to 
know how to add up facebook activity from your application. Remember that, you need to generate APP ID from your facebook account to connect facebook from your application.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply but i am already using facebook-sdk-3.0.1 and the link of your tutorial is from the older sdk so the calls there are deprecated. Also all i want is to display the registration page of facebook.